# How to get selected radio type input and use it as a variable?

Tags: php, javascript, html, radio-button

How can i get the selected radio input type value in a php script and direct it to a different directory to retrieve the files selected. I tried writing the code, but couldn't write it properly since i m a newbie in the world of php.

The code i have written for displaying radio button is

```
<input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $orderby1[0]; ?>"  
id="<?php echo $orderby1[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $orderby1[0]; ?>"  
/><?php echo $orderby1[0]; ?>
```

Now how to get the selected values from it and direct it to the directory contains the file?

The code i have written is , which doesn't seems to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.getElementById("<?php echo $orderby1[0]; ?>");
jmolApplet(400, "load  /jmol/'element.value'.txt");  
</script>
```

I don't want to include any for loops... that makes my script work differently.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `$_REQUEST` method within a form, something like:

```
<?php 
  if ($_REQUEST['radiotest']) {
    echo "You chose ".$_REQUEST['radiotest'];
  }
?>
<form>
  <div><input type='radio' name='radiotest' value='1' /> Option 1</div>
  <div><input type='radio' name='radiotest' value='2' /> Option 2</div>
  <div><input type='radio' name='radiotest' value='3' /> Option 3</div>
  <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to execute when the radio has rendered and then not put the value inside the quotes

```
function someEvent() {
  var element = document.getElementById("<?php echo $orderby1[0]; ?>");
  jmolApplet(400, "load  /jmol/"+element.value+".txt");  
}
```

Comment: if i use a forloop, the whole script is running only if user selects a radio button. But i need the script to run all time before user selects the input..

Comment: Sorry, that I did not understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I really do not understand your question